# Passing PChar from Delphi DLL to C

Tags: c++, delphi, delphi-xe2

I am currently having trouble importing a Delphi DLL dynamically.
The Delphi DLL function is declared as here :

```
function TEST() : PChar; cdecl;
begin
  Result := '321 Test 123';
end;
```

In C++ I am calling it this way:

```
typedef char *TestFunc(void);
TestFunc* Function;
HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary("Test.dll");
if (hInstLibrary)
{
    Function = (TestFunc*)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary, "TEST");
    if (Function)
    {
        printf("%s", Function());
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am only receiving the first letter of the string.
How can I tell C++ that the string is not ending after the first char?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of delphi?  You need to know if the char is 1 or 2 bytes.

Comment: Or try using PAnsiChar.

Comment: I am using Delphi Xe2

Comment: Wow. the PAnshiChar was just what I was looking for! Thanks so much!

Comment: @user2227015 That only fixes one of your problems. The other problem is harder to fix.

Comment: Also you probably want `stdcall` as the calling convention.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff No. The C code used `cdecl`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right, let me rephrase it: The default calling convention i would expect of DLL functions is stdcall. Of course OP would have to fix this on both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. The string that Delphi is sending to you is UTF-16 encoded. You'd need to encode as ANSI and return `PAnsiChar`, if you want to match up against `char*`.
2. The memory that the returned pointer refers to is liable to be deallocated when the function returns. You get away with it in your function since you return a string literal which is held as a global constant that endures for the lifetime of the DLL. For a string variable, you will encounter runtime errors when your caller tries to read memory that has been deallocated. To confuse matters, those runtime errors will be intermittent. Your code may appear to work. Expect failures when you deploy to your most important customer!

Your options to solve item 2:

1. Arrange that the caller allocates the buffer, which can then be populated by the callee.
2. Allocate and deallocate the string on a shared heap. For example the COM heap with `CoTaskMemAlloc` and `CoTaskMemFree`. Using a shared heap allows you to allocate in one module, and deallocate in the other.

As a rule of thumb, always prefer option 1 if it can meet your needs.

Comment: I don’t really get what problem 2 is about.
Since the string is passed correctly, I can just transfer the value of the pointer to another string so that it doesn’t matter if the original return is deallocated, can I?

Comment: You are not interested in the "value of the pointer". You are interested in the memory that it refers to. And if that memory is be deallocated when the function returns, your C code then has an invalid pointer. Reading from that memory is then undefined behaviour. So if you had a Delphi string named `mystr` and you wrote `Result := PAnsiChar(mystr)` in your DLL function, you would be in trouble. The memory that `Result` refers to would be deallocated when the function returned.

Comment: Option 3: allocate in dll (eg GetMem) and export deallocation routine from the DLL